# HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello I had to rewrite my user model for add some filed, I used AbstractUser

My models:
It's on blog app:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL , related_name='articles' , verbose_name='نویسنده')...
```

it's on account app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_authour = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="وضعیت نویسندگی")
    special_user = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="کاربر ویژه تا")    

    def is_special_user(self):
        if self.special_user > timezone.now():
            return True
        else:
            return False 
    
    is_special_user.boolean = True
    is_special_user.short_description = "وضغیت کاربر ویژه"
```

I imported my User view in this way:

```
from account.models import User
```

And I added this to my setting:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.User'
```

when I migrate I get this error:

> blog.Article.author: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the
> model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
> HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

I searched my error but I can't find my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `User` passed to the `ForeignKey` points to the `auth.User` right now, not your custom `User`.

As the HINT itself suggests, use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of `User` in your `author` field in `Article` model.

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='articles', verbose_name='نویسنده')...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of referring to `User` directly, you should reference the user model using `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`. This method will return the currently active user model – the custom user model if one is specified, or User otherwise.

Example:

```py
django.contrib.auth import get_user_model()

User = get_user_model()
```

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='articles', verbose_name='نویسنده')...
```

`Referencing the User model` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Answer (score -1):

Link to django docs: [Using a custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Did you register the model in the app's `admin.py`?

Furthermore, changing the user model mid-project...this can be a hassle, look here: [Changing to a custom user model mid-project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project)

Answer (score -2):

I think you are importing User model from django auth app.

Change the `author` field in the Article model as follows:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('account.User', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='articles', verbose_name='نویسنده')
    ...
```